# Using CRTP for mocking classes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, crtp

I am trying to mock classes that do not have any virtual functions. I had read that [Curiously_recurring_template_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP) can help in achieving that.

here is the code. I am trying to unit-test function `getMyClassValue`

```
// file myclass.h
template<typename T>
struct MyClass_t {
    int hello() {
        return (static_cast<T*>(this))->hello_impl();
    }
};

/*
 Earlier MyClassImpl was just simple class like
 struct MyClassImpl {
    int hello() {
       return 110;
     }
 };

 // I changed it to below for making it mockable. Using CRTP.
*/

struct MyClassImpl : public MyClass_t<MyClassImpl> {
    int hello_impl() {
        return 110;
    }
};

typedef MyClassImpl *MyClass;

int getMyClassValue(MyClass doc) { 
    return doc->hello(); 
}

// file main.cpp
#include <iostream>
/*
int main() {
    MyClass myclass = new MyClassImpl();
    std::cout << getMyClassValue(myclass);
    delete myclass;
    return 0;
}
*/

// file test.cpp
struct MyClassImplTest : public MyClass_t<MyClassImplTest>, 
                         public virtual MyClassImpl {
    int hello_impl() {
        return 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto myclass = new MyClassImplTest();
    std::cout << getMyClassValue(myclass);
    delete myclass;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting `110` in console and not `2`.
Why is that happening ? Since i am using pointers, slicing should not happen.

How do i achieve the mocking?

Comment: What is the interface that you intend to test?

Comment: `getMyClassValue` is the function that i want to test..

Comment: I doubt it's possible to mock a non-templated object parameter with your CRTP trick. `getMyClassValue` would have to be a function template for that to work.

Comment: This link https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/mocking-in-c-the-virtual-problem/ said "Using some kind of CRTP for static dispatching: probably one of the cleanest solutions, but I think it adds too much overhead to the definition of each class." Did i misunderstood it ?

Comment: Well, the blogger doesn't go into the details at all. Perhaps he's implicitly accepting that the limitation of only testing templated interfaces is OK. Or maybe it didn't even occur to him. In a comment he says "I’ve never actually seen this technique used “in the wild”." Have you considered asking the author about the technique?

Comment: can not post a reply in the blog post.. :( something weired happening..

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this has nothing to do with slicing. What happens is quite simple, really:

- `getMyClassValue` accepts a pointer of type `MyClassImpl*` and calls `hello`
- Call resolves to `hello` in the parent of `MyClassImpl` which is `MyClass_t<MyClassImpl>`
- `hello` static casts the pointer to `T*` which is `MyClassImpl*` and calls `hello_impl`
- `MyClassImpl::hello_impl` returns 110

The call to `hello` cannot resolve to the `MyClass_t<MyClassImplTest>` parent of `MyClassImplTest` because it's called on a pointer of type `MyClassImpl*` and not with a pointer of type `MyClassImplTest`. Trying to call `hello` on `MyClassImplTest*` wouldn't work either unless you specify which parent to use, because the call would be ambiguous.

Achieving mocking with virtual functions would be simple. Without, not as much.

Comment: `getMyClassValue` is the function that i want to test.. and then how do i achieve the mocking of MyClassImpl ?

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass` is a pointer to `MyClassImpl`. Calling `hello` on it calls `MyClass_t<MyClassImpl>::hello`, which casts `this` to `MyClassImpl*` and thus calls `MyClassImpl::hello_impl`.

If you're using compile-time "polymorphism" (CRTP), all the types must be correct at compile-time.

I believe the only way to make this work would be to make *everything* a template. You'd simply pass around the implementation types as template parameters/arguments. An example for `getMyClassValue` would be this:

```
template <class T_MyClass>
int getMyClassValue(MyClass_t<T_MyClass> *doc)
{
  return doc->hello();
}

struct MyClassImplTest : public MyClass_t<MyClassImplTest>
{
    int hello_impl() {
        return 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto myclass = new MyClassImplTest();
    std::cout << getMyClassValue(myclass);
    delete myclass;
    return 0;
}
```

This would have to apply to all production code and all test code. It could be made more feasible by gathering all the types into a "type context" which would store the implementation type of each interface. This would then be explicitly passed around.

```
struct ProductionContext
{
  typedef MyClassImpl MyClass;
  typedef MyClass2Impl MyClass2;
};

struct Mock1Context
{
  typedef MyClassImplTest MyClass;
  typedef MyClass2Impl MyClass2;
};

struct Mock2Context
{
  typedef MyClassImpl MyClass;
  typedef MyClass2ImplTest MyClass2;
};

template <class T_Context>
int getMyClassValue(typename T_Context::MyClass *doc)
{
  return doc->hello();
}

int main()
{
    auto myclass = new MyClassImplTest();
    std::cout << getMyClassValue<Mock1Context>(myclass);
    delete myclass;
    return 0;
}
```

Again, every bit of production and test code would have to be templated by `T_Context`. To prevent the need from having everything header-only, you could explicitly instantiate the templates with all contexts you'd intend to use.

For me, this would be prohibitively unwieldy, but it *is* a solution.

---

Side note: please don't hide pointers behind typedefs. `typedef MyClassImpl *MyClass;` is pure obfuscation and would *never* pass code review with me.

Comment: if i would templatize `getMyClassValue` then i do not need CRTP altogether..? Isn't it ? if you read the first multiline comment at first 10 lines of the code..

Comment: @AshishNegi Well, in a way you're right. The thing is, just like all templates, CRTP is purely *compile-time.* If you want to use a mock type, that fact has to be communicated to the function using it at compile time. If that's not what you want, use runtime polymorphism - virtual calls.